# infopath cascaded dropdown displaying lookup field values in 1;#ABC format. Need to format the value as ABC without id

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint, infopath

I have a browser enabled infopath form with a dropdown box(cascaded), the data being retreived from an xml document. The data is in the following format-(as the value is retrieved from a lookup field.)

item_number;#item_value

how to show only the item_value in the dropdown box. Can I apply rules to the dropdown box or is there any way through code to achieve this?

Thanks for the help!

I found a similar post here [cascaded dropdown look up field](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/9964/35310.aspx) but there are no proper solutions

I found a solution but have trouble making it work,
I am using a file query connection to get the data for the dropdown, i will be executing the connection and populating an xml document with the result. I am having trouble writing the content to xmldocument, see my question here-

[Infopath FileQueryConnection.Execute(XpathNavigator) throws System.Net.WebException: Attempted to read or write protected memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712295/infopath-filequeryconnection-executexpathnavigator-throws-system-net-webexcepti)

I guess if this is solved, everything will be fine.

Comment: If i´am right the dropdown is a infopathcontrol, so you must edit this control in infopath and change the output.

Comment: @myName :where to change and what to change...I cant edit the displayed value from the dropdown list properties, i tried applying rules, but of little use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

```
 private void formatValue(string dataSourceName, string xPathSTring)
    {
        FileQueryConnection con = (FileQueryConnection)DataConnections[dataSourceName];
        con.Execute();
        DataSource ds = this.DataSources[dataSourceName];
        XPathNavigator nav = ds.CreateNavigator();
        XPathNavigator root = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
        XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(xPathSTring, NamespaceManager);
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {

            string value = iterator.Current.Value;
            int startFrom = value.IndexOf('#') + 1;
            iterator.Current.SetValue(value.Substring(startFrom, (value.Length - startFrom)));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using XPath Expression and do this

```
substing-after(YourFieldName, '#')
```

Comment: If I get the query output to an xml document I can apply this formatting.But I am facing problem with my FileQueryConnection - see the link in my question, do you know where else to use this formatting in infopath to achieve the same?

Comment: Why are you using http://server_name/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll? can you use the normal web service methods in Sharepoint?

Comment: Using web service is my last option. I might be getting that error because i m trying to read from the owssvr.dll without any proper authentication...I am not sure. Thanks anyways, if there is no workaround for this I will go by web services.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an extra calculated column to show clear data.

Comment: Hmmm,sounds good! but my columns are all of 'Look up' type and they are not supported in Calculated Columns.